# jQuery get element without use of onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, onclick

I'm trying to get the element id (or data attribute for that matter) of a HTML input without the use of onclick. My code:

```
<button class="button primary" type="button" onclick="add_poll_answers(30)">Submit</button><br />
```

Here is my jQuery function:

```
function add_poll_answers(id)
{
    var answers = [];
    var i = '0';
    $('input[id^="new-answer-'+id+'"]').each(function() {
        answers[i] = $(this).val();
        ++i;
    });
    $.post("index.php?module=actions&action=edit_poll&process=add",
    {
    pollid: id,
    answer: answers,
},
function(data, status)
{
    if (data != '')
        alert(data);
        else
            $("#ajax_add_"+id).slideDown();
    });
}
```

What I need is some way of removing the onclick and just adding it to a separate jQuery file. I can't just use the following because there is more than one poll per page and the IDs would clash. What I really need is a way for you to click something, like below, and then jQuery can dynamically get the element's data attribute for the id of the poll. In other words, I want the javascript to get the id without the need to pass it on using onclick.

Does anyone have any idea how this might be accomplished?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#edit_poll").click(function()
    {
       edit_poll();
    });
```

(the id edit_poll doesn't exist, this is only theoretical)

I can't find anything related to my own question, and I'm getting pretty confused about this. I'm fairly new to AJAX to start with, but this is really puzzling me. I know there is a way to do it but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some way to identify the buttons that you want to handle, and then you either:

1. Hook `click` on them directly:

   ```
   $("button").on("click", function() {
       // Use `this` here to access the element, e.g.
       // its ID is `this.id`, or you can access a
       // data attribute via `$(this).attr("data-foo")`
       // or this.getAttribute("data-foo")
   });
   ```
2. Hook `click` on a *container* element and tell jQuery to only notify you if the click happened on one of these buttons, which looks very similar:

   ```
   $("selector for the container").on("click", "button", function() {
       // Use `this` here to access the element, e.g.
       // its ID is `this.id`, or you can access a
       // data attribute via `$(this).attr("data-foo")`
       // or this.getAttribute("data-foo")
   });
   ```

   This is called *event delegation* and it's very handy in those situations where you'll be adding/removing buttons on-the-fly.

In the above, I've just used `"button"` as the selector for the button, but of course you'll want something more specific — you might, for instance, add a class to the buttons in question and use `".the-class"` instead.

Example of #1 (directly handling clicks):

```js
$(".poll").on("click", function() {
  $("<p>")
    .html("You clicked " + $(this).attr("data-value"))
    .appendTo(document.body);
});
```

```html
<div>
  <button type="button" class="poll" data-value="1">Choose 1</button>
  <button type="button" class="poll" data-value="2">Choose 2</button>
  <button type="button" class="poll" data-value="3">Choose 3</button>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Example of #2 (using event delegation):

```js
$("#container").on("click", ".poll", function() {
  $("<p>")
    .html("You clicked " + $(this).attr("data-value"))
    .appendTo(document.body);
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <button type="button" class="poll" data-value="1">Choose 1</button>
  <button type="button" class="poll" data-value="2">Choose 2</button>
  <button type="button" class="poll" data-value="3">Choose 3</button>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: You only need to use `ready` if you don't control where the script tags on your page go. If you do, just put the script tag containing your code at the end of the page, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly it, it helped me to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#edit_poll").click(function()
    {
       var id=$(this).data("pollid");
       add_poll_answers(id);
    });
});
```

where your element has data-pollid attribute

Answer (score 0):

Create a button that holds this information.

```
<button class="button primary addAnswer" type="button" data-pollid="30">Submit</button>
```

Then simply make all buttons (or select just some buttons using a class) trigger a function that will look for the ID.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button.addAnswer").click(function () {
        add_poll_answers($(this).data("pollid"));
    });
});
```

Comment: The problem with this method is there are multiple buttons on the same page for editing, adding and removing. Sorry if that part wasn't clear

Comment: Then you can mark one type of buttons using a css class (like I did in the example - I added `addAnswer` class to that button), then simply apply certain function only to these buttons.

Answer (score 0):

If you need more elements to apply the same, just use the class attribute to identify the element:

```
<button class="buttonClick button primary" type="button">Submit</button>
```

then, handle the event with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".buttonClick").click(function(){
       console.log($(this).attr('id')); //to get the id, class or whatever
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
var a = document.querySelector(".theClasseYouWantToListen").textContent;
console.log(a)
    });
```

this is how i trick the doom and